# How can I set default variables in hover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I unhover I want to get default text of my button but if I define my default text button on unhover it give me a manipulated text but I want to get default text how can I do that ?

```js
$('button').each(function(){
    var dataColor = $('this').data('color');
  $(this).css({
    color:dataColor,
  });
  $(this).hover(function(){
    var defaultButtonText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('SALE');
  },function(){
      $(this).text(defaultButtonText);
  });
})
```

```css
button{
  width:10%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  margin:5%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-color="#cc0033">A button</button>
<button data-color="#396786">B button</button>
<button data-color="#CC99FF">C button</button>
```

Comment: Declare `defaultButtonText` outside `.hover()`

Comment: in the second callback, defaultButtonText is out of scope because you only declared it inside the first callback. You should read up on variable scoping in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('button').each(function(){
    var dataColor = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).css({
    color:dataColor,
  });
  var defaultButtonText = "";
  var newColor =''; 
  $(this).hover(function(){
    defaultButtonText  = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('SALE');
   $(this).css('background-color', $('this').attr('data-color'));
  },function(){
      $(this).text(defaultButtonText);
     $(this).css('background-color', $('this').attr('data-color'));
  });
})
```

```css
button{
  width:10%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  margin:5%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-color="#cc0033">A button</button>
<button data-color="#396786">B button</button>
<button data-color="#CC99FF">C button</button>
```

Comment: then it gave me a this error line: 'pen.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: defaultButtonText is not defined'

Comment: here is run successfully

Comment: here is run successfully ... its problem in your pen.js ... you can also try rename  defaultButtonText  variable ..

Comment: but it must give a color text for each button

Comment: please check my last edit .. do you want like this ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the variable `defaultButtonText` outside of the functions in which you want to use it:

```js
$('button').each(function(){
    var dataColor = $('this').data('color');
  $(this).css({
    color:dataColor,
  });
  
  var defaultButtonText = $(this).text(); 
  
  $(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).text('SALE');
  },function(){
      $(this).text(defaultButtonText);
  });
})
```

```css
button{
  width:10%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  margin:5%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-color="#cc0033">A button</button>
<button data-color="#396786">B button</button>
<button data-color="#CC99FF">C button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('button').each(function(){
    var dataColor = $('this').data('color');
  $(this).css({
    color:dataColor,
  });
  $(this).hover(function(){
    //var defaultButtonText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('SALE');
  },function(){
      $(this).text($(this).attr("data-text"));
  });
})
```

```css
button{
  width:10%;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#fff;
  padding:12px;
  margin:5%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-color="#cc0033" data-text="A button">A button</button>
<button data-color="#396786" data-text="B button">B button</button>
<button data-color="#CC99FF" data-text="C button">C button</button>
```

1. Since you have data attribute in your OP make use of that attr. Set a data-text then set it as default then on un hover set it again sa text of button

Comment: Very interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you don't need the `each()` loop here, you can work on the elements as a group.

Secondly, to set the original text value back on mouseleave you can set it in a data attribute which can be read when the event occurs. Try this:

```js
$('button').css('color', function() {
  return $(this).data('color');
}).hover(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).data('hover-text'));
}, function() {
  $(this).text($(this).data('original-text'));
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-color="#cc0033" data-original-text="A button" data-hover-text="SALE">A button</button>
<button data-color="#396786" data-original-text="B button" data-hover-text="SALE">B button</button>
<button data-color="#CC99FF" data-original-text="C button" data-hover-text="SALE">C button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not redefine `defaultButtonText` variable in `hover` event handler:

```js
$('button').each(function() {
  var dataColor = $('this').data('color');
  $(this).css({
    color: dataColor,
  });
  var defaultButtonText=$(this).text();
  $(this).hover(function() {
    $(this).text('SALE');
  }, function() {
    $(this).text(defaultButtonText);
  });
})
```

```css
button {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-color="#cc0033">A button</button>
<button data-color="#396786">B button</button>
<button data-color="#CC99FF">C button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure CSS:

```
button:before {
    content: "Default Text";
}
button:hover:before {
    content: "Hover Text";
}
```

Bonus, on click text:

```
button:active:before {
    content: "Hover Text";
}
```